# Change Python substring by removing []

Tags: python, regex, string, substring

I have a problem in Python which I can't solve. I have for example this text:

```
--Es que[103-l] haré todo ese trabajo por muy poco precio, casi
     de balde....
```

So I want to manipulate that text so I can erase the `[103-1]`. Is there a simple way to do it? Like a way to say "Remove from '[' to ']' ".
Thanks!

Comment: Use the regular expression `\[.*?\]` and replace it with an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple regex:

```
import re

s = "--Es que[103-l] haré todo ese trabajo por muy poco precio, casi de balde...."

print(re.sub("\[.*?\]", "", s))
```

This should print:

```
--Es que haré todo ese trabajo por muy poco precio, casi de balde....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression. Its a bit complicated because "[" and "]" are control characters in regex's so they need to be escaped. The following says to match "[" then a non-greedy match of anything until the next "]"

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "--Es que[103-l] haré todo ese trabajo por muy poco precio, casi de balde...."
>>> re.sub(r"\[.*?\]", "", text)
'--Es que haré todo ese trabajo por muy poco precio, casi de balde....'
>>>
```